# How to authorize user to update only a document that matches his `_id` in CouchDB?

Tags: authentication, authorization, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to model a profiles database, where every profile is public for authenticated users, and where each user can only update his/her own profile.

Each profile document `_id` will be the email of the registered user, and I modeled the following `validate_doc_update` function:

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) { 
  var id = userCtx.roles[0].substring(5);
  if (newDoc._id !== id) {
    throw({forbidden: "One can only update one's self document."});
  }
}
```

I tested the database and it worked perfectly as I expected. Am I getting this right? Is there any flaw or breach?

(I'm using [SuperLogin](https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin) for creating and login-in the users)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a viable solution. I'd check for the roles prefix to be "user:" just to be safe, and maybe you can also allow users with the role "_admin" to edit any document.

One possible problem with your solution might be that you are probably exposing the email addresses of all your users if you use the email as the id. But if you're ok with that in your particular use case, your solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is SuperLogin. It creates a document in the `_users` database to represent a session of a given user.

When the user logs in, [SuperLogin creates a new session](https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin/blob/master/lib/user.js#L561-L636) that inserts a document that looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": "org.couchdb.user:iwn9IpwNR4i0wrxmYcGarg",
   "_rev": "1-0f36c9e220c41fe54726cdd01adcdcf2",
   "password_scheme": "pbkdf2",
   "iterations": 10,
   "type": "user",
   "name": "iwn9IpwNR4i0wrxmYcGarg",
   "user_id": "aasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaandremiramor@gmail.com",
   "expires": 1458027109739,
   "roles": [
       "user:aasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaandremiramor@gmail.com",
       "user"
   ],
   "derived_key": "9a6cfaaac2249ef74fba599c3fbede65a48dcd32",
   "salt": "1ef2689337699061b9460f6f68f63f28"
}
```

The `roles` array is also created by [SuperLogin](https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin/blob/master/lib/dbauth/couchdb.js#L14) using the username. Since I had it configured to use the email as the username (`{emailUsername: true}`), the e-mail was could be matched as the corresponding document `_id`.